# Groovy HttpBuilder getting header's value

Tags: java, groovy, syntax, maps, httpbuilder

I'am trying to get headers in from HttpBuilder and confused about difference between using `headers."Header name"` and `headers["Header name"]`

```
HTTPBuilder builder = new HTTPBuilder();
builder.setUri("https://stackoverflow.com/")
builder.request(Method.GET) {
    response.success = { resp ->
        def header1 = resp.headers."Strict-Transport-Security"
        def header2 = resp.headers["Strict-Transport-Security"]
        println("Header toSting: ${header1}, Header class: ${header1.class}") //result: Header toSting: max-age=15552000, Header class: class java.lang.String
        println("Header toSting: ${header2}, Header class: ${header2.class}") // result: Header toSting: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000, Header class: class org.apache.http.message.BufferedHeader
    }
}
```

So results are different. Can you explain how it works? I was sure that `something."key"` is the same as `something["key"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you use those syntaxes on.

If you use those syntaxes on a `Map`, you are right.

But the `headers` field is not a `Map`, but a [HeadersDecorator](http://javadox.com/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.6/groovyx/net/http/HttpResponseDecorator.HeadersDecorator.html) instance that provides those different syntaxes. Just click on the link to get to the respective JavDoc.

Using Operators in Groovy is just about methods being called and you can even override them to change operator behavior. In the case of `Map`, `getAt(Object)` does the bracket syntax retrieval of the value, `propertyMissing(String)` does the dot notation retrieval of the value if there is no object property with that name.

In case of the `HeadersDecorator` `getAt(String)` does the bracket syntax retrieval of the `Header` object and `propertyMissing(String)` does the dot notation retrieval of the value of the header if there is no object property with that name.